# How to sort nested dictionary by values in python

Tags: python, sorting

**PROBLEM**

I have a dictionary and it is nested i want to sort it using vlaues. There are many solution out there for the same question but I couldnt find one solution that satisfies my sorting condition

**CONDITION**

I want to sort thee dict in descending order of the given likes in the dict

**Dict**

```
dict = {actor_name: {movie_name: likes}

eg:- {'gal gadot': {'red notice': 1000}, 'tom holland': {'spiderman-nwh': 3000}}

output should be:- {'tom holland': {'spiderman-nwh': 3000}, 'gal gadot': {'red notice': 1000}}
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort descending on likes?

Comment: sorry i am sorting it on descending order on likes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest improving your data structure first.
As an example you could use a list of dictionaries `list[dict]`.

This would help you later, if you expand your structure.

Try this structure:

```py
data = [
    {
        "actor": "gal gadot",
        "movies": {
            "name": "red notice",
            "likes": 1000,
        },
    },
    {
        "actor": "tom holland",
        "movies": {
            "name": "spiderman-nwh",
            "likes": 3000,
        },
    },
]
```

Using that structure, you can sort your data like this:

```
# Least likes first
least_likes_sorted = = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x["movies"]["likes"])

# Most likes first
most_likes_sorted = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x["movies"]["likes"], reverse=True)
```

Comment: This is definitely much better as it's more structured. I'd suggest going even further and creating instances from a class rather than a dictionary.

Comment: @Ted You're right, but I think it depends on the level of knowledge. I tried to explain it as simple as possible from assuming the perspective of the questioner. There is always room for improvement. :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't mean for this answer. I meant it as a tip to future readers. From the question, this is a great answer! Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list of tuples where each element is (likes, movie, actor).

Then sort the list in reverse.

Then reconstruct your dictionary.

Like this:

```
data = {'gal gadot': {'red notice': 1000}, 'tom holland': {'spiderman-nwh': 3000}}
lot = []
for k, v in data.items():
    k_, v_ = next(iter(v.items()))
    lot.append((v_, k_, k))
newdata = {a : {b: c} for c, b, a in sorted(lot, reverse=True)}
print(newdata)
```

**Output:**

```
{'tom holland': {'spiderman-nwh': 3000}, 'gal gadot': {'red notice': 1000}}
```